# AWS EC2 instance IP not resolving by Route53 pointed domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, godaddy-api

I was trying to point my domain from Godaddy to the AWS EC2 Ip address using AWS Route53. I have added a new IPV4 A address as the EC2 instance and added a new CNAME record as www.codehacks.in. And also I have updated all four nameservers from AWS to the GoDaddy DNS nameserver section.

I installed ghost cms on the server to check ip resolving or not. But, getting a `The connection has timed out` error on almost all browsers.

I have checked the whois info to check the domain pointed to a new IP address. In fact, it's properly pointed to the AWS nameservers.

So is there anything else I have to do to make the domain point to the EC2 instance? Please check the below screenshot for the Route53 configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make sure your ec2 security groups have ports 80 and 443 accessible, I pinged the website and it's resolving to the correct IP so it's not DNS issue.

Comment: Yes there was only port 22 was allowed to connect to my instance. I have created a new security group which allows incoming request for all ports and then it worked. Thanks a lot.